# Creating Saving and Loading Materials in Runtime

Tags: unity, materials, rendertexture

I'm trying to create a material during runtime like this:

1. In my Assets I have a Render Texture and one Material
2. I created an Script where I attach the Render Texture to Material
3. I save in my project a PNG Image File for later use

   ```
   public void CreateAndSaveMaterial(){

   RenderTexture.active = _renderTexture;
   Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(_renderTexture.width, _renderTexture.height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
   tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, _renderTexture.width, _renderTexture.height), 0, 0);
   tex.Apply();

   File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + url, tex.EncodeToPNG());

   tempObject.mainTexture = tex;
   RenderTexture.active = null;
   ```

   }

*The PROBLEM:

1.The Material works in rutime, after quit playing, the Material resets :(
2.The created PNG File not working only if the file is reimported in Unity, I tried with:

```
AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(obj, fileName);
AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
AssetDatabase.Refresh();
```

But unsuccessfully, works only in Editor not in build app :(

Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance!